# return the same record more than once in a query result

Tags: mysql

The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

will return three records.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,1);
```

will return just two records (for Ids 1 and 2)

Is there a way for the result set to contain two records for Id 1 (and three in total)?

Comment: Create a table that contains the ids you want and then join to that table ON id.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use mysql to do a presentation job of display a row twice rather than constraining is purpose to data retreival

Comment: I suspect danblack's on the right path, but anyway see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a table for the ids you want to filter by. This would get you your desired results. I'm not sure if mysql supports CTE, but hopefully this is enough for you to get the idea.

```
WITH IDS
AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id
)
SELECT T.*
FROM T
JOIN IDS
ON T.id = IDS.id
```

Comment: mysql 8 and mariadb 10.2+ support cte